# How to remove old Hibernate Search index

Tags: indexing, hibernate-search

I use Hibernate search for full text search in my web application. I have button for index creation in admin panel. I do it by this code:

```
                fullTextSession.createIndexer()
                .purgeAllOnStart(true)
                .optimizeAfterPurge(true)
                .optimizeOnFinish(true)
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects( 25 )
                .threadsToLoadObjects( 5 )
                .threadsForSubsequentFetching( 20 )
                .startAndWait();
```

If index was build correctly and then I push this button again old index files still on disk and program creates new index. And so on. Can you help me remove old index files before creating new?

Answer (score 4):

I do a similar thing but only when I shut my app down do I remove the indexes and then I set them up again on startup.

Have you tried calling purgeAll() instead of purgeAllOnStart()? That is what I call on app shutdown and it works. To be safe, after I purge the indexes I actually delete my index directory and all files / folders it contains from disk as well.

Comment: I've got an [answer](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1010245) on the HIbernate Search forum